# How to refer to a user in chat with their UIDs?

Tags: telegram

I have an array of User IDs which I've set as admins and I would like to print them to clients when they call the `/admins` command.

The main issue is that I couldn't see or find a way to print a placeholder entity (it's `mention` in this case) which opens a chat window with the IDs I've specified.

Remember that when you post `@username` in a chat, Telegram simply binds it as a mention to the referenced user and it jumps on a chat window when you click on it. I wonder if there is an equivalent for `@123456789`, where the number represents the User ID.

Comment: Do you want to do with programatically or actually just within the app its self?

Comment: @Jack If there was a setting in the app just for this, it'd be great. If not, I am open-minded to any programmatical advice on how to solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately, only bot can do that at this time :(

Comment: @Sean In fact, I'm not trying to send messages via User IDs. I'm just looking for a way to bind them just like in the `@username` which generates a clickable entity. It'd be nice to see Telegram implemented this feature, referring via User IDs. However, yes, currently there is no remedy for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create/send a message from a bot, you can set `parse_mode` to `HTML`, then send text/caption with HTML anchor tag same this:

```
for contact me, just <a href="tg://user?id=123">click here</a>
```

but if you want to send message as user, you can just use `userName` prefixed by `@`, and creating manual link to `tg://user?id=123` or type plain text like `tg://user?id=123`, don't work in Telegram now. yes; just in iOS (less than 15% of Telegram user) that work since 2013!

Comment: That did it. Thanks.